# Pattern only number with/without 2 decimals

Tags: html

I wanted to know what is the pattern to ask for a positive number,no zero and that has or does not have decimals, but if you have decimals that has 2,

I have this

```
 pattern="[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{0,2})"
```

true 
1.44
1
12341234
9893
65.69

false
asdasd
1f
f56
1e10

Comment: Can you describe more ? What do you want exactly

Comment: I need a number to be mandatory. this number must be positive and no zero. it can contain decimals and if it contains only 2 decimals.